# Passing headers in HTTP.get

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I’m working on a project and I’m dealing with JWT, anyway I have tried to send post requests and it went as a charm but when I tried to make get requests the same way is not working.
here is my code :

```
ionViewWillEnter(){

this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
 this.token = val 

console.log(this.token);
let link = Constants.API_ENDPOINT+"/v1/owner/section/list";
console.log("Debugging");
console.log(link);

this.http.get(link,{},{Authorization: "Bearer "+val})
.then(data =>{
  var hdrs = JSON.parse(data.headers);
  var res = JSON.parse(data.data);

  console.log(res);
  console.log(hdrs)
})
.catch(error =>{
  console.log("Yup Errors area ")
  console.log(error.status);
console.log(error.error); // error message as string
console.log(error.headers);

});
});
}
```

I get the following output :

```
 Debugging
(the correct link)
Yup Errors area ["a message I have set to make sure that the code    executed the catch method"]
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

so basically I get an error , but ionic won't show it!

**Note :**

I have sent a request to the same link with the same headers in `Postman` and it returned the correct response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt your response HTTP headers are in JSON format themselves, which is implied by this line:

`var hdrs = JSON.parse(data.headers);`

Your headers are probably just a map of key/value pairs, not JSON encoded. I wonder if that line is throwing an exception thereby aborting the rest of the on success handler.

Comment: I have added that after I got these errors , anyway I have removed it and now I got the the error number 500